# Replacing escape in JSON LinkedHashMap Object on Android

Tags: android, json, escaping, linkedhashmap

I have this code in Android:

```
Map<String, String> idObject1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            idObject1.put("Id", "Test1");
            idObject1.put("FirstName", "Test Name");
            idObject1.put("LastName", "Test Surname");
            idObject1.put("PhoneNumber", "12345");
Gson gson = new Gson();
json.put("ParticipantIds", gson.toJson(idObject1));
Log.d("Json", json.toString());
Log.d("ParticipantsJson", gson.toJson(idObject1).toString());
```

The json object also gets other things added to it via the `.put` method. It's only messing up at the "ParticipantIds" key.

```
json.toString()
```

Outputs

```
{"ParticipantIds":"{\"Id\":\"Test1\",\"FirstName\":\"Test Name\",\"LastName\":\"Test Surname\",\"PhoneNumber\":\"12345\"}",
```

and

```
gson.toJson(idObject1).toString());
```

Outputs

```
{"Id":"Test1","FirstName":"Test Name","LastName":"Test Surname","PhoneNumber":"12345"}
```

I need to remove the `\` occurances in the json object when `idObject1` is passed into it. It doesn't necessarily have to use Gson. I only used Gson in an attempt to get it to work. I've also tried:

```
json.put("ParticipantIds", idObject1);
```

and tried using JSON-Simple to pass it in. I always get the `\` escaped character.
I've even tried doing `.toString()` on `idObject1` then doing all manner of `.replace` and `.replaceAll` methods on it. It doesn't work!

Comment: what is the issue with \ escaped character. When you are using " character within String then String changed to \". So I don't think escaped character occurs any problem. When you try to parse that json string then you able to parse, I mean no exception occurs to parsing that json string.

Comment: The server doesn't like the \ in the object, I need it removed.

Comment: You should communicate with server guys because json string with escaped character don't create any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u get JsonString replace that escape sequence as given below this works for removing escape sequences

```
  json.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","");
```